# For GCP app engine, sepcifying order of installation of dependencies with requirements.txt

Tags: google-cloud-platform, dependencies, requirements.txt

My app deployment to gcp app engine is failing because the order of installation of dependencies is not matching what is required. I don't see any other way of specifying the order either in requirements.txt or in gcp app engine deployment options. Can anyone suggest a solution or a workaround please?

Comment: Why dependencies have an order? They should be self sufficient to be installed in any orders.

Comment: @RanaBanerjee as suggested by  guillaume blaquiere this should not be an issue. In order to try to help you further would you mind posting a [minimum reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of the app you are trying to deploy (including your app.yaml file) as well as the exact dependencies you are using on the requirements.txt file? Adding the `--verbosity=debug` to the `gcloud app deploy` command could also be useful to get the exact error message as to why your deployment is failing.